# Editing a Wordpress plugin to add my own functionality

Tags: php, user-registration

I'm trying to add more fields to this php script. By default what it does is allow visitors to your site to input their name and email address to register it into a list on the back end, which I can then export as a .csv file. At the moment I'm attempting to add fields for phone number, city, state, ect. I've been able to add the fields, but they don't register on the back end. Actually when I finish adding a field, it breaks every other field. Here is my php code. Anything referencing number, or sml_number is what I'm trying to add.

Edit: I wasn't being clear enough. I *think* the problem is in the end of sml.php.

Below are what I think the problems might be.

```
            // Handle form Post
            if ($_POST['sml_subscribe']) {
                $name = $_POST['sml_name'];
                $email = $_POST['sml_email'];
                $number = $_POST['sml_number'];
                if (is_email($email)) {

                    $exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where sml_email like '".$wpdb->escape($email)."' limit 1");
                    if (mysql_num_rows($exists) <1) {
                        $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_name, sml_email, sml_number) values ('".$wpdb->escape($name)."', '".$wpdb->escape($email)."', '".$wpdb->escape($number)."')");
                    }
                }
            }
```

and

```
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and $_POST['sml_import']) {
                            $correct = 0;
                            if($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
                                if(!$_FILES['file']['error'])  {
                                    $file = file_get_contents ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                                    $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $file);
                                    if (count($lines)) {
                                        $sql = array();
                                        foreach ($lines as $data) {
                                            $data = explode(',', $data);
                                            $num = count($data);
                                            $row++;

                                            if (is_email(trim($data[0]))) {
                                                $c = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where sml_email LIKE '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."' limit 1", ARRAY_A);
                                                if (!is_array($c)) {                                            
                                                    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_email, sml_name, sml_number) VALUES ('".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[1]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."')");
                                                    $correct++;
                                                } else { $exists++; }
                                            } else { $invalid++; }
                                        }

                                    } else { $message = 'Oh no! Your CSV file does not apear to be valid, please check the format and upload again.'; }

                                    if (!$message) {
                                        $message = $correct.' records have been imported. '.($invalid?$invalid.' could not be imported due to invalid email addresses. ':'').($exists?$exists.' already exists. ':'');
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    $message = 'Ooops! There seems to of been a problem uploading your csv';
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
```

And below is the entire contents of the plugin for reference.

sml.php:

```
            // Plugin Activation
            function sml_install() {
                global $wpdb;
                $table = $wpdb->prefix."sml";
                $structure = "CREATE TABLE $table (
                    id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    sml_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                    sml_email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                    sml_number VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
                );";
                $wpdb->query($structure);

            }
            register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sml_install' );

            // Plugin Deactivation
            function sml_uninstall() {
                global $wpdb;

            }
            register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'sml_uninstall' );

            // Left Menu Button
            function register_sml_menu() {
                add_menu_page('Subscribers', 'Subscribers', 'add_users', dirname(__FILE__).'/index.php', '',   plugins_url('sml-admin-icon.png', __FILE__), 58.122);
            }
            add_action('admin_menu', 'register_sml_menu');

            // Generate Subscribe Form 

            function smlsubform($atts=array()){
                extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                    "prepend" => '',  
                    "showname" => true,
                    "nametxt" => 'Name:',
                    "nameholder" => 'Enter your name.',
                    "emailtxt" => 'Email:',
                    "emailholder" => 'Enter your email address.',
                    "numbertxt" => 'Phone Number:',
                    "numberholder" => 'Enter your Phone Number.',
                    "showsubmit" => true,
                    "submittxt" => 'Subscribe',
                    "jsthanks" => false,
                    "thankyou" => 'Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list!'
                ), $atts));

                $return = '<form class="sml_subscribe" method="post"><input class="sml_hiddenfield" name="sml_subscribe" type="hidden" value="1">';

                if ($prepend) $return .= '<p class="prepend">'.$prepend.'</p>';

                if ($_POST['sml_subscribe'] && $thankyou) { 
                    if ($jsthanks) {
                        $return .= "<script>window.onload = function() { alert('".$thankyou."'); }</script>";
                    } else {
                        $return .= '<p class="sml_thankyou">'.$thankyou.'</p>'; 
                    }
                }


                if ($showname) $return .= '<p class="sml_name"><label class="sml_namelabel" for="sml_name">'.$nametxt.'</label><input class="sml_nameinput" placeholder="'.$nameholder.'" name="sml_name" type="text" value=""></p>';
                $return .= '<p class="sml_email"><label class="sml_emaillabel" for="sml_email">'.$emailtxt.'</label><input class="sml_emailinput" name="sml_email" placeholder="'.$emailholder.'" type="text" value=""></p>';
                $return .= '<p class="sml_number"><label class="sml_numberlabel" for="sml_number">'.$numbertxt.'</label><input class="sml_numberinput" name="sml_number" placeholder="'.$numberholder.'" type="text" value=""></p>';
                if ($showsubmit) $return .= '<p class="sml_submit"><input name="submit" class="btn sml_submitbtn" type="submit" value="'.($submittxt?$submittxt:'Submit').'"></p>';
                $return .= '</form>';

                return $return;
            }
            add_shortcode( 'smlsubform', 'smlsubform' );

            // Handle form Post
            if ($_POST['sml_subscribe']) {
                $name = $_POST['sml_name'];
                $email = $_POST['sml_email'];
                $number = $_POST['sml_number'];
                if (is_email($email)) {

                    $exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where sml_email like '".$wpdb->escape($email)."' limit 1");
                    if (mysql_num_rows($exists) <1) {
                        $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_name, sml_email, sml_number) values ('".$wpdb->escape($name)."', '".$wpdb->escape($email)."', '".$wpdb->escape($number)."')");
                    }
                }
            }

            function plugin_get_version() {
                $plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );
                $plugin_version = $plugin_data['Version'];
                return $plugin_version;
            }

            ?>
```

index.php

```
<div class="wrap">

    <?php screen_icon( 'themes' ); ?>
    <h2>Mail list subscribers</h2>

    <div id="poststuff">

        <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-3">

            <!-- main content -->
            <div id="post-body-content">

            <form method="post" action="?page=<?php echo esc_js(esc_html($_GET['page'])); ?>">
            <input name="sml_remove" value="1" type="hidden" />
                        <?php 
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and $_POST['sml_remove']) {
                            if ($_GET['rem']) $_POST['rem'][] = $_GET['rem'];
                            $count = 0;
                            if (is_array($_POST['rem'])) {
                                foreach ($_POST['rem'] as $id) { 
                                    $wpdb->query("delete from ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where id = '".$wpdb->escape($id)."' limit 1"); 
                                    $count++; 
                                }
                                $message = $count." subscribers have been removed successfully.";
                            }
                        }

                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and $_POST['sml_import']) {
                            $correct = 0;
                            if($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
                                if(!$_FILES['file']['error'])  {
                                    $file = file_get_contents ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                                    $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $file);
                                    if (count($lines)) {
                                        $sql = array();
                                        foreach ($lines as $data) {
                                            $data = explode(',', $data);
                                            $num = count($data);
                                            $row++;

                                            if (is_email(trim($data[0]))) {
                                                $c = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where sml_email LIKE '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."' limit 1", ARRAY_A);
                                                if (!is_array($c)) {                                            
                                                    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_email, sml_name, sml_number) VALUES ('".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[1]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."')");
                                                    $correct++;
                                                } else { $exists++; }
                                            } else { $invalid++; }
                                        }

                                    } else { $message = 'Oh no! Your CSV file does not apear to be valid, please check the format and upload again.'; }

                                    if (!$message) {
                                        $message = $correct.' records have been imported. '.($invalid?$invalid.' could not be imported due to invalid email addresses. ':'').($exists?$exists.' already exists. ':'');
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    $message = 'Ooops! There seems to of been a problem uploading your csv';
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                        //echo $sql;
                        if ($message) { echo '<div style="padding: 5px;" class="updated"><p>'.$message.'</p></div>'; }

                        ?>

                        <table cellspacing="0" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed subscribers">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-cb check-column" id="cb" scope="col"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-name" id="name" scope="col">Name<span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-email" id="email" scope="col"><span>Email Address</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-number" id="number" scope="col"><span>Number</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>

                           </thead>

                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-cb check-column" scope="col"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-name" scope="col"><span>Name</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-email" scope="col"><span>Email Address</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-number" scope="col"><span>Number</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                            </tfoot>

                            <tbody id="the-list">

                            <?php 

                                $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml");
                                if (count($results)<1) echo '<tr class="no-items"><td colspan="3" class="colspanchange">No mailing list subscribers have been added.</td></tr>';
                                else {
                                    foreach($results as $row) {

                                        echo '<tr>
                                                    <th class="check-column" style="padding:5px 0 2px 0"><input type="checkbox" name="rem[]" value="'.esc_js(esc_html($row->id)).'"></th>
                                                    <td>'.esc_js(esc_html($row->sml_name)).'</td>
                                                    <td>'.esc_js(esc_html($row->sml_email)).'</td>
                                                    <td>'.esc_js(esc_html($row->sml_number)).'</td>

                                              </tr>';




                                    }
                                }

                            ?>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br class="clear">
                        <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Remove Subscribers" /> <a class="button" href="<?php echo plugins_url( 'export-csv.php', __FILE__ ); ?>">Export List</a>
                </form>
                <br class="clear">


                <div class="meta-box-sortables">



            <div id="postbox-container-1" class="postbox-container">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables">

                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
            <br class="clear">
    </div>

</div>
```

export-csv.php

```
<?php 
require_once '../../../wp-load.php';
if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="subscribers'.date('YmdHis').'.csv"');  
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml");
    echo "First Name,Last Name,Email Address\r\n";
    if (count($results))  {
        foreach($results as $row) {
            $n = doSplitName($row->sml_name);
            echo $n['first'].','.$n['last'].','.$row->sml_email."\r\n";
        }
    }
}

function doSplitName($name) {
    $results = array();

    $r = explode(' ', $name);
    $size = count($r);

    if (mb_strpos($r[0], '.') === false) {
        $results['salutation'] = '';
        $results['first'] = $r[0];
    } else {
        $results['salutation'] = $r[0];
        $results['first'] = $r[1];
    }

    if (mb_strpos($r[$size - 1], '.') === false) {
        $results['suffix'] = '';
    } else {
        $results['suffix'] = $r[$size - 1];
    }

    $start = ($results['salutation']) ? 2 : 1;
    $end = ($results['suffix']) ? $size - 2 : $size - 1;

    $last = '';
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        $last .= ' '.$r[$i];
    }
    $results['last'] = trim($last);

    return $results;
}
?>
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. Or even just a push in the right direction. I've been working on this for weeks, and I'm not terrific at php. Thank you very much.

Comment: Better try to add and retrieve a single field. So far there's much too many code that one would likely be willing to read, test, debug, etc. Then come back, [edit] your question and tell where you're stuck, what works, etc.

Comment: What @kaiser said, plus... editing a plugin is generally a bad idea. Your changes will be lost when the plugin is updated.

Comment: I revised the question, adding where I *think* the problem might be.

Also it doesn't really concern me if the plugin gets updated at all. As far as I'm concerned this is now my version of the plugin for my own personal use if that makes sense. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Are you doing this to learn or does this plugin do something special the other 4000 address list form plugins don't do? Certainly there are others out there that will allow you to add fields easily via the admin.

Comment: Well yes, I am still learning php, but in general I haven't seen a plugin that will do what I use this one for. IE make a field where users can input their name/email address, and output that information to an easily extractable .csv not an email list like mailchimp. If you know of any could you recommend one to me?